# I can't see the branch I build in x-code testing in Testflight

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight

I have received a react-native project from a company I actualized the UI for the android and ios version, I have used git and created another branch to do this, I prepare my app to publish in ios, I exported to App store connect I send it by test flight to myself, and when I open the app for testing, what I have installed is the first version not the customized UI in the branch I have created the x code build, why this is happening?

I have merged my branch with the master and uploaded again and again but nothing happens I steel seeing the previous UI

I have received an email with an error message in the app store connect

TMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

But I think is not related, what could be the solution to this?

Comment: The Below UIWebView Api is not an issue , they still accept the builds, check if you increased the build number and the build that is there to download matches the build number you added. Also check the activity tab to ensure that the . build you added have completed processing

Comment: Hi, Anjula thank you, yes I check the tab and it wasn't processed, it was rejected a few minutes ago.

Comment: My pleasure. An up vote wont hurt though xD